# Materials about S-matrix and S-matrix theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, scattering, s-matrix-theory

What is the best book or paper to learn about analytical structures of [S-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) and [S-matrix theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix_theory)?

I already know books as *The Analytic S-matrix* by RJ Eden, PV Landshoff, DI Olive, JC P and *Quantum Field Theory* by S. Weinberg.

Comment: Badger, Henn, Plefka & Zoia, _Scattering Amplitudes in QFT,_ [arXiv:2306.05976](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.05976).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found chapters in books on regge theory as:

- (P. D. B. Collins) An Introduction to Regge Theory.
- (Geoffrey F. Chew) S-Matrix Theory of Strong Interactions.
- (S. C. Frautschi) Regge Poles and S-Matrix Theory.
- (V. N. Gribov) The Theory of Complex Angular Momenta.

Comment: Please see the banner above and in particular the site [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/4698_ on resource recommendation questions. We tend to strongly frown on answers which only provide book titles without any sort of commentary.