# Any good references on the analytic structure of scattering amplitudes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, scattering, s-matrix-theory, analyticity

In papers they often say things about the analytic structure of S matrices - things like resonances are poles on the unphysical sheet, particle channels cause a square root branch cut etc.

I've seen this demonstrated in a couple of simple cases but I was wondering if there was any book/notes where this is talked about in general?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105138/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

In general analyticity is consequence of causality and unitarity.
A classic text is Eden, Landshoff and Polkinghorne *The analytic S-Matrix*.  It focusses on $S$-matrix elements, but discusses the analytic properties of individual Feynman diagrams.